# JS setattribute is not a function- Firefox, chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this JavaScript function:

```
function Test(isValid) {    
    var divStart = $get('divDateFrom');
    var divEnd = $get('divDateTo');
    var txtStartDate = divStart.firstChild;
    var txtEndDate = divEnd.firstChild;
    var isValidFromForecastStartDate;
    txtEndDate.setAttribute('dateInRegionalFormat', txtEndDate.value);
}
```

This function is working fine in IE but I'm getting "`txtEndDate.setattribute` is not a function" error in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: SetAttribute should work, pls check whether you get correct object in "txtEndDate"

Comment: Can you post your whole code in Js fiddle pls

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [jquery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) like,

```
$(txtEndDate).attr('dateInRegionalFormat', txtEndDate.value);
```

**Updated** there may be `multiple elements` so use `[0]` for the `first element` like,

```
txtEndDate[0].setAttribute('dateInRegionalFormat', txtEndDate.value);
```

You should **first check** whether the `elements exists or not` before `setting attribute` in it like,

```
if(txtEndDate.length)
{
   txtEndDate.setAttribute('dateInRegionalFormat', txtEndDate.value);
}
```

Comment: this is Java script, So it would be good if you could provide the solution in Java script. Thanks

Comment: @SyedKalim see my updated answer, or can you make a `online demo on fiddle`?

Comment: @RohanKumar first child only returns one element not an array of elements

Comment: So what would be the solution?

Comment: @Rohan,,,txtEndDate[0].setAttribute('dateInRegionalFormat', txtEndDate.value); it is throwing exception...i don't know why?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by this way:

```
txtEndDate['dateInRegionalFormat'] = txtEndDate.value;
```

instead of old code:

```
txtEndDate.setAttribute('dateInRegionalFormat', txtEndDate.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same kind of issue very recently. Try to get rid of ".value" part. It may work for you.

```
txtEndDate.setAttribute('dateInRegionalFormat', txtEndDate);
```