# Adding a class to a <p> to animate the <p> element then removing that class once the animation is over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate a `<p>` element when the user makes a choice. The element will animate when I add the class in the inspector, but I can't seem to add the class with JavaScript. I was able to add the class before, but now I can't even get that to work anymore.

```js
// const for faster calculations
const ROCK = 0;
const PAPER = 1;
const SCISSORS = 2;

let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
var userScoreText = $("#userScore");
var computerScoreText = $("#computerScore");

function game(userChoice) {
    // removeMyClass();
    if (userChoice == "rock") {
        userChoice = ROCK;
    } else if (userChoice == "paper") {
        userChoice = PAPER;
    } else {
        userChoice = SCISSORS;
    }
    // Get a computer to make a choice
    let computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    // Test the outcomes of the user vs computer
    if (computerChoice == userChoice) {
        alert("Tie " + computerChoice);
    } else if (computerChoice == SCISSORS && userChoice == ROCK) {
        alert("You won");
        userScore++;
        userScoreText.addClass("animateMe", 2000, removeMyClass);
        userScoreText.addEventListener("animationend", removeMyClass);
    } else if (computerChoice == ROCK && userChoice == SCISSORS) {
        alert("Computer Won");
        computerScore++;
        $("#computerScoreText").addClass("animateMe");
        $("#computerScoreText").on("animationend", removeMyClass);
    } else if (computerChoice > userChoice) {
        alert("Computer Won");
        computerScore++;
        $("#computerScoreText").addClass("animateMe", 2000, removeMyClass);
        $("#computerScoreText").addEventListener("animationend", removeMyClass);
    } else {
        alert("You Won");
        userScore++;
        $("#userScoreText").addClass("animateMe", 2000, removeMyClass);
        $("#userScoreText").addEventListener("animationend", removeMyClass);
    }
    // Display the outcome
    alertUserOfOutcome(userChoice, computerChoice);
    // First one to 5 wins
    updateScore();
}

function removeMyClass(){
    console.log("Here");
    $("#userScore").removeClass("animateMe");
    $("#computerScore").removeClass("animateMe");
}

function alertUserOfScore(userScore, computerScore){
    alert("The score is:\n" + "You: " + userScore + "\nComputer: " + computerScore);
    if (userScore == 5){
        alert("You won the game");
        userScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0;
    } else if (computerScore == 5){
        alert("The computer won the game");
        userScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0;
    }
}

function updateScore(){
    userScoreText.innerHTML = userScore;
    computerScoreText.innerHTML = computerScore;
}

function alertUserOfOutcome(userChoice, computerChoice) {
    userChoice = intToChoice(userChoice);
    computerChoice = intToChoice(computerChoice);
    alert("You Chose: " + userChoice + "\nComputer Chose: " + computerChoice);
}

function intToChoice(intToChange) {
    if (intToChange == ROCK) {
        return "Rock";
    } else if (intToChange == PAPER) {
        return "Paper";
    } else {
        return "Scissors"
    }
}
```

```css
.animateMe {
    animation-name: shake;
    animation-duration:  1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}


@keyframes shake {
    0% {
        transform: scale(50%);
    }
    20% {
        transform: rotate(var(--first)) scale(var(--first-scale));
    }
    40% {
        transform: rotate(var(--second)) scale(var(--first-scale));
    }
    60% {
        transform: rotate(var(--first)) scale(var(--first-scale));
    }
    80% {
        transform: rotate(var(--second)) scale(var(--first-scale));
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="score">
        <p>Your Score:</p>
        <p id="userScore">0</p>
    </div>

<div class="game_buttons_container">
    <input type="image" src="./images/granite.png" onclick="game('rock')" alt="Rock">
    <input type="image" src="./images/paper.png" onclick="game('paper')" alt="Paper">
    <input type="image" src="./images/scissors.png" onclick="game('scissors')" alt="Scissors">
</div>
```

How do I go about getting these elements to animate? Is there a way to hit play on an animation? That would be a lot easier than trying to add and remove a class to an element.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: How is this a minimal reproducible example? when you can't see anything other than a single div with the user score?

Comment: Ohh sorry, You are right. I forgot you need to press a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are two problems here.

Problem one is I was incorreclty accessing the `element` I wanted.

```js
// This returns a list of elements with the id computerScore
// This can not use the setAttribute function
var computerScoreText = $("#computerScore");

//This returns the p element that can use the setAttribute function
var userScoreText = $("#userScore")[0];
```

Use `var userScoreText = $("#userScore")[0];`

Now to solve the problem of animating the the element.

```js
function animateScore(scoreToAnimate) {
//This will add the class to the element you want to animate
    scoreToAnimate.setAttribute( "class", "yourAnimationClass" );
//This will remove the class once the animation has played for 2 seconds. 
    setTimeout( function() {
        scoreToAnimate.setAttribute( "class", "" );
    }, 2000);
}
```

[This shows how to get the correct element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650768/js-setattribute-is-not-a-function-firefox-chrome)